# Hey. Don't tap on the glass

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

A man works at an aquarium. Every day, he has to spend way too much time telling people to stop tapping on the glass at the shark tank. Finally, he gets fed up with it and comes up with a solution.

Thankfully, the solution works perfectly, because the next day, nobody tapped on the glass. At the end of his shift, though, he was fired for it.

What did the man do?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes...

Comment: I think it's because there's not an "obvious" answer to this problem. That is, there's not an answer you can objectively say is correct. I think this meta post is relevant: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/why-are-questions-off-topic-if-they-invite-answers-which-are-not-demonstrably-co

Comment: Thanks for directing me to that thread. I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He put a decal of cracked glass on it, so it looks like it's just about to break.

He could also have **actually** cracked it, but let's just assume he's grumpy and not downright insane :-)

Answer (score 1):

He removed the fish tank and cooked the shark - served it as a fish dish.

All went well, untill the restaurant owner came in to pick up the cash from the day, only to notice his beloved shark tank and the tank are gone. The fact that is was cooked and eaten by the diners enraged the owner to the point where he fired the culprit.

Comment: But when the owner ate a bite of shark meat, he immediately committed suicide.

Comment: Combining this with the salmon suicide riddle is a long shot..

Answer (score 0):

He simply removed all of the glass himself.  No glass, not even a chance of someone tapping on it.

Of course, since all the animals in the tank died for it, he was fired.

Comment: I'd hope someone would notice quite a while before the end of his shift that he'd taken all the glass out of the shark tank :P

Comment: @Joe They clearly had a lot more to do before firing him from his job.  An entire aquarium full of water and dead fish doesn't clean itself, you know.